# Don't include the brief description in the detailed description when using Doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen, documentation-generation

I am using Doxygen with C++ and with `JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF` set to `YES`. Is it possible to not include the brief description in the detailed description? Is there a way to configure this in the Doxyfile maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an option named `REPEAT_BRIEF`, take a look at it.